# Settings view in an application in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios4, user-interface

I am pretty new to iPhone dev. I want to create a Settings page in my application. In Android i use preferences to fill the required Settings page. Is there anything like that for iPhone dev, or should i create every section like a normal UI.

BR,
Suppi

Answer (score 1):

See [Implementing Application Preferences](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Preferences/Preferences.html) in the iOS Developer Library. This will give you all the information you need and some *best practices* to follow.

You could also use something like [InAppSettingsKit](http://inappsettingskit.com/) which works in an almost identical fashion but will allow you to present your app preferences in-app as well as via the Settings.app.

Comment: After looking at these examples, i would like to clarify something, so in iPhone you can not add settings in your own application. And can be added only via Settings of the device? am i right?

Comment: If you want to add your own settings and build a custom UI to support them then obviously you can but it'd be up to you how you store that data and present it to the user. Using a Settings.bundle is Apple's recommended way to achieve Application Preferences but they are only accessible via the Settings.app. InAppSettingsKit works as a middle man, mirroring the look of the Settings.app but allowing you to display and update the same preferences in-app. I would recommend following Apple's guide above + using InAppSettingsKit.

Comment: Thanks alot, gives a better understanding. Now say for example i use Apple's recommended way, i want to give a section for username and password login,can i give 2 buttons login and cancel, and on click of login, i need to verify the username and password. Can i do something like this in the Settings.app itself?

Comment: Afraid not. You can only assign values, you cannot call methods; in-fact you cannot even display buttons. However, you can define extra sections that will appear only in the InAppSettingsKit version which can be buttons and which can call methods, but these will only be displayed in-app, not in Settings.app. If you download the source code for InAppSettingsKit there is a really useful demo project which shows off all of this really well.

Comment: yeah i was thinking the same, i had a look at the InAppSettingsKit as well. Seems pretty neat. Maybe these kind of features i should put it in my application with some buttons. Now incase i have a Toggle Switch in Settings.app, and can i change the value of it from myapp. I know i can retrieve the value.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a "settings page" in Settings app, you should look at **`Settings.bundle`** with **`NSUserDefaults`**.

Comment: Thanks alot, i want to add settings o nly in my app.

Comment: So you should follow @micpringle's instructions instead.